# Spawn socket server, return port, and continue running

Tags: php, multithreading, sockets

I'm looking to have a web application spawn a socket server thread in the background.  Each PHP session gets its own thread, and there can be any number of threads.

I bind the socket using a port of zero, so that it picks a random open port.  My socket server starts correctly, and moves into it's listening loop without issue.  The issue I have, however, is that my PHP script that starts the thread using `shell_exec()` needs to get a response from the thread indicating which port must be used to communicate.  The problem is that if I start the thread and wait for a response, the client script will sit and wait for the server thread to complete, instead of moving on and communicating with it via sockets.

Is there a way for PHP, when run from CLI or shell_exec() to say, "Okay, that's the last of my output, go ahead and continue on."?

My structure is mostly as follows:

Server.php

```
Start socket listener
Output chosen port
Do { Application Loop }
```

Client.php

```
Start Session
If !Session['port'] {
    Start Server.php, receive Port //This is where it waits forever
}
Communicate with server thread via Port
```

I hope this is clear.  Please comment if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP_THREAD](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php) :)
Also, you can take a look to my Github project, it includes Socket and Thread examples and i think that it can help you : [ANYEM_THREAD_TEST](https://github.com/Halayem/ANYEM/blob/master/ANYEM_CLIENT/anyem.client.tst/AnyemClientMultiThreadTest.php)

Comment: I'm a bit shady on how Thread may work in my case.  I assume my server would establish the socket, send back the port to the client, pass the socket into a thread, then exit, thereby releasing the client to continue?